Transaction got stuck in indexing
I've used safe-infrastructure repo to deploy safe on Viction chain.
I can create the safe and send a transaction of VIC transfer successfully: https://www.vicscan.xyz/tx/0x930a267f13221e571772e3b4ee944b526b88927f97c9993d0d0e8f0edd01c435
But the transaction is stuck in indexing.
When I look at the logs in txs-worker-indexer I found this:
txs-worker-indexer-1  | 2024-10-31 05:05:57,289 [ERROR] [68807896/index_safe_events_task] Block with hash=0x90c0932663355225be97542f9532018dfd8c47eb204621b8d82f2ed8bc85e08a does not exist on database
txs-worker-indexer-1  | 2024-10-31 05:05:57,306 [ERROR] [68807896/index_safe_events_task] Task safe_transaction_service.history.tasks.index_safe_events_task[68807896-4440-473e-8b75-945145144f7f] raised unexpected: DoesNotExist('EthereumBlock matching query does not exist.')
txs-worker-indexer-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 453, in trace_task
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 736, in __protected_call__
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/app/autoretry.py", line 38, in run
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     return task._orig_run(*args, **kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/utils/celery.py", line 59, in wrapper
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
txs-worker-indexer-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/tasks.py", line 242, in index_safe_events_task
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     number, number_of_blocks_processed = SafeEventsIndexerProvider().start()
txs-worker-indexer-1  |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/indexers/ethereum_indexer.py", line 501, in start
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     ) = self.process_addresses(
txs-worker-indexer-1  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/indexers/ethereum_indexer.py", line 408, in process_addresses
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     processed_elements = self.process_elements(elements)
txs-worker-indexer-1  |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/indexers/events_indexer.py", line 291, in process_elements
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     processed_elements = self._process_decoded_elements(decoded_elements)
txs-worker-indexer-1  |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/indexers/safe_events_indexer.py", line 655, in _process_decoded_elements
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     creation_events_processed = self._process_safe_creation_events(
txs-worker-indexer-1  |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/indexers/safe_events_indexer.py", line 568, in _process_safe_creation_events
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     internal_tx = self._get_internal_tx_from_decoded_event(
txs-worker-indexer-1  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/indexers/safe_events_indexer.py", line 302, in _get_internal_tx_from_decoded_event
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     ethereum_block_timestamp = EthereumBlock.objects.get_timestamp_by_hash(
txs-worker-indexer-1  |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/models.py", line 275, in get_timestamp_by_hash
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     return self.values("timestamp").get(block_hash=block_hash)["timestamp"]
txs-worker-indexer-1  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
txs-worker-indexer-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 649, in get
txs-worker-indexer-1  |     raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
txs-worker-indexer-1  | safe_transaction_service.history.models.EthereumBlock.DoesNotExist: EthereumBlock matching query does not exist.

Although I could find both the block and the transaction in Django administration on /txs/admin


Here's .env for safe-infrastructure
REVERSE_PROXY_PORT=80

CFG_VERSION=latest
CGW_VERSION=latest
TXS_VERSION=latest
UI_VERSION=latest
EVENTS_VERSION=latest

RPC_NODE_URL=https://rpc.viction.xyz


I've found that the issue came from RPC and not the safe 
